# How to add custom calculated fields to a pivot table (Excel 2010).

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am new to pivot tables and Excel in general and I am struggling with the following problem: I have a table populated with data, and from this table I want to perform some data analysis. The Excel table structure is given below. The idea is that every row corresponds to a particular product:

[image]

Based on this table I have created a pivot table, where each row should contain information about the supplier. The first row was easy to create and it simply counts the product for the particular supplier:

[image]

Now I want to add two more calculated fields in the pivot table. The first one should sum the value in the `Has Subscription?` column for each supplier. This would result in summing `TRUE+TRUE+TRUE+TRUE` for `Supp1`, `FALSE+FALSE+FALSE` for 'Supp2' and so on. I have tried using `SUMIF COUTIF and SUM(IF(..))` but I can't get it working. The second calculated field I want to insert is about counting the certificate (marked by `X`) column for each supplier. If we are looking at certificate 1 this should result in `2` for `Supp1`, `0` for `Supp2` and `3` for `Supp3`. I thought that

`=COUNTIF( 'Certificate 1 required' ,"X")`

would do the job but again I end up with incorrect formula error. I think that Excel can't link the Suppliers to the columns I am interested in but I am not sure how to fix that. Or maybe I need Power Pivot for this task? I don't know so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source table starts on Cell A1:
For your first calculated column:

`=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$11,"=TRUE",A$2:A$11,"=Supp1")`

For your second calculated column:

`=COUNTIFS(F$2:F$11,"=x",A$2:A$11,"=Supp1")`.

Try that and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I get `References, Names and Arrays are not supported in PivotTable formulas` when I run the formulas.